Evaluating trigonometry expressions with non-trivial angles
There are numerous trigonometry problems that asks us to evaluate an expression with non-trivial angles (i.e. angles whose sine and cosine values we are not normally familiar with) but no variables. For example:
Evaluate
$$k=\frac{2\cos20^\circ-\sin10^\circ}{\cos10^\circ}.$$
There are often nice solutions using trigonometry identities and the reduction formulas , but such solutions are not easy to come up with. Are there any ultimate general methods to tackle this type of problem?
I seem to have a method that works brutally.
With the example above, let
$$2\cos20^\circ-\sin10^\circ=k\cos10^\circ,$$
then
$$2-4\sin^210^\circ-\sin10^\circ=k\sqrt{1-\sin^210^\circ}.$$
Square both sides and we get $\sin10^\circ$ is a root of
$$f(x)=16x^4+8x^3-\left(15-k^2\right)x^2-4x+4-k^2=0.$$
Notice that the minimum polynomial of $\sin10^\circ$ is $g(x)=8x^3-6x+1$ (obtained by $\frac12=\sin\left(3\cdot10^\circ\right)$). Hence $g\mid f$, and we solve out $k=\sqrt3$.
I made use of the fact that $10$, $20$ are divisible by $10$, which simplifies the problem. If the gcd is smaller, then the degree of $f$ and $g$ would be much larger, increasing the difficulty.

Yes. There are several techniques. Some common methods which are used for the evaluation of finite non trivial trigonometric sums are: Use of trigonometric identities and algebraic identities efficiently; through counter integration techniques (see for example: non trivial trigonometric sums by B. C. Berndt et. al); there is a way of evaluating trigonometric sums through Ramanujan's theory of theta functions (see for instance Trigonometric sums through Ramanujan's theory by Harshitha et.al); there is also discrete Fourier Analysis technique to evalues finite trigonometric sums.

Consider the following method to find $k$:$$k=\frac{2\cos(30^\circ-10^\circ)-\sin10^\circ}{\cos10^\circ}=\frac{\sqrt3\cos10^\circ+\sin10^\circ-\sin10^\circ} {\cos10^\circ} =\sqrt3,$$is this what you call "use of trigonometric identities and algebraic identities efficiently"? @Yathi
